# Vsphere html web client 6.7 sdk

Tags: vsphere

I recently downloaded the latest sdk and somehow my custom plugins are not working in virgo server. It is giving me errors like:

- Load denied by X-frame options
- Refuse to display  in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('deny, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'.

Is anyone facing such issues with latest sdk. I am using 6.7 web client sdk with 6.7 Vcenter.

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue when the UI bundle is deployed through Eclipse using Virgo tools.

The issue should not manifest when you do hot deploy i.e. throw your bundles into the `server/pickup` folder.

A fix for the issue should be available in an upcoming update.

The [release notes for the 6.7 SDK](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/8b3adca2-ec47-4a13-be9f-0ec8fafd349e/c562c305-3a7e-4ccf-81c6-41a8ba472650/vsphere-client-sdk-67-release-notes.html#vsphere-client-sdk-known) mention another issue the workaround for which should solve your problem too. The issue is *Virgo server using incorrect context path when started from Eclipse.*

The solution is to pass the following VM arguments to the Virgo instance that gets started from Eclipse (by editing its launch configuration):

     `-Dweb.context.path.match=vsphere-client
     -Dweb.context.path.replace=ui`

Comment: Thanks, I figured out and used the second solution of adding some arguments in the launch configuration..Thanks again